# Make font-weight normal in autocomplete by event keyup

Tags: jquery, events, if-statement, autocomplete

I want to mimic the Google suggestion list, so I have an autocomplete for the suggestions but I also want to **bold** the font if it does not match the value of input, here is an example: [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/epikim/27/edit)

As you can see I have set **bold** for CSS for suggestions and I'm trying to make it normal if it is the same as value:

```
if($('#input').val() == $('.ui-autocomplete li a').text()){
       $('.ui-autocomplete li a').css("font-weight", "normal");
}
```

No luck so far. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('.ui-autocomplete li a').text()` isn't comparing any *one* element, or each of them individually, but instead this seems to concatenate all possibilities, so that by the time you've typed "gho" the comparing looks something like this:

```
if ("gho" == "ghost riderghost huntersghost rider 2ghost adventuresghost rider spirit of vengeanceghanaghbghetto hikesghostbusters 3ghost") {

}
```

Another problem, the same in nature, is that

```
$('.ui-autocomplete li a').css("font-weight", "normal");
```

will change the style for all found matches. Neither behaviour isn't what you want, I suspect.

What you probably want is something like this:

```
$("#input").on('keyup', function(e){
  var val = $('#input').val();
  $.each($('.ui-autocomplete li a'), function() {
    if (val == $(this).text()) {
      $(this).css("font-weight", "normal");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Did not know about $.each:)...This makes perfect sence to me, I can read and understand this. What I don't understand is that it doesn't work..I thought to override autocomplete settings by !important in the jquery `.css("font-weight", "normal !important");` But it still doesn't work...Do you have any idea why that is?

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
$("#input").on('keyup', function(e){
      var val = $('#input').val();
      $.each($('.ui-autocomplete li a'), function() {
        if (val == $(this).text()) {
          $(this).addClass('fontWeight');
        }
      });
});
```

add css should be

```
  .ui-autocomplete li a {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .fontWeight{
    font-weight:normal !important;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but it doesn't work:( I think changes should be made NOT in an event but in the autocomplete right after function(item) {